# Correct use of jQuery .data

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to attach an alphanumeric string to a set of nodes; each node has a string (which is not unique).

Then I need a click handler that filters by that string's value. I see jQuery's .data() function will store the strings on the nodes, but then I can't select on them. Am I supposed to create the nodes using the `attr` property like this:

```
var node = $('<div class="node"></div>').attr('data-string', "18nn4v");
```

And then filter like this?

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    $('.node[data-string="18nn4v"]')...//whatever
});
```

It would be nice if I could just use `.data()`. It just seems a little lopsided since jQuery automatically imports all `"data-XXX"` attributes into that element's property: `.data(XXX)`, but it does not export all `.data(XXX)` properties to `"data-XXX"` attributes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery attribute selector works only on genuine attributes -- i.e. what has been defined in the original HTML or by `setAttribute` (used by jQuery's [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)).  This is by design and is correct behaviour.

If you want to use `data`, you'll have to do the filtering manually with [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
$('.node').filter(function() {
    return $.data(this, 'string') === "18nn4v";
}).
```

Comment: I see. I guess it just seems a little lopsided since jQuery automatically imports all `"data-XXX"` attributes into that element's property: `.data(XXX)`, but it does *not* export all `.data(XXX)` properties to `"data-XXX"` attributes!

Comment: @Jasie Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr/5884994#5884994). It may explain some of this stuff.